# Better way to convert a nested array of PSObjects to strings for Export-Csv?

Tags: powershell, tostring

I've got a PSCustomObject containing nested arrays of objects I need to be able to pipe it to `Export-Csv` or `Export-Excel` without losing any data. I don't know in advance what properties the object will have or which ones are going to be arrays themselves.

`$ArrayofComplexObjects` is my input data which comes from a log extract. The actual number of fields and their types varies with each data extract I run depending on the precise log entries in the extract period. For example the last extract had around 80 properties, 60 of which were objects and any of which could themselves have been arrays of objects depending on the data in that particular log entry. The remaining properties were a mixture of Strings and Ints.

```
$ArrayOfStrings = @()
$ArrayofComplexObjects | ForEach-Object {
    $LineItem = @{}
    $_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        $LineItem.Add($_.Name, ($_.Value | Out-String ))    
    }
    $ArrayOfStrings += New-Object PSObject -Property $LineItem
}

$ArrayOfStrings | Export-Csv .\temp.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It's important to keep the export in a format that's non-techie friendly and can be attached to an incident log.

The code is working, but I've got a very strong feeling that I've missed something obvious and have reinvented the wheel. Is there a better/simpler/more elegant way to do it?

Comment: generally, one uses `.ToString()` and `-join '; '` to convert complex objects into delimited strings. without seeing the actual objects in question, tho, i can't get any more detailed than that.

Comment: It's the output from Search-UnifiedAuditLog after conversion from JSON. One line could be an email deletion with half a dozen fields containing one selection of objects, the next could be a federated login to Azure with an entirely different set of fields and sub objects. I've already expanded out the fields by getting unique property names and using that with select-object against the results of convertfrom-json.

Comment: thanks for the added info. [*grin*] you will likely need to expand each complex object & then join the desired props into strings if you want to preserve that info. since you want to convert `kinda-readable` data into `easily readable` data ... that means you are going to need to do each property set manually and then structure your output text manually. ///// there is a _reason_ JSON was created to be `kinda readable` ... [*grin*]

Comment: Tell me about if! It wouldn't be so bad if MS had given the various logs a consistent format. There are even two different fields for client IP address - Exchange calls its "ClientIPAddress", but Azure, OneDrive and SharePoint call it "ClientIP". I'm getting fields in the export that are  a big block of multi-line text, but at least the data is there. I'm nervous about expanding the sub-objects in case the property names clash with something else. Actor contains 3 fields called ID for example, one's the ObjectID of the account, one's the UPN, and I've not found where the third comes from yet.

Comment: ouch! then "people readable" output will require you to parse everything and build the strings by hand for the items that don't gracefully string-ify. good luck! [*grin*]